# Redisplay brew Post Installation Text

Tags: macos, homebrew

Often, when I'm using the [brew package manager](https://brew.sh/) to install tools and programatic environments onto my Macintosh computer, there will be some important text at the end of the instalation that describes some nuance of using what I just installed.  For example, after installing redis, you'll see something like the following

```
$ brew install redis
# ... lots of stuff ...
==> Caveats
To restart redis after an upgrade:
  brew services restart redis
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

Short of running `brew uninstall [thing];` and then rerunning `brew install [thing];`, is there a way to have brew redisplay this text?

If not -- given this text comes from some program somewhere, is there a way I could grab the brew -- package? (not sure that's the right term) -- and find this text in a well structured data file or program somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called "Caveats" and are printed with `brew info`. See below for an example with `youtube-dl`:

```
$ brew install youtube-dl
...
==> Caveats
To use post-processing options, `brew install ffmpeg` or `brew install libav`.

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /home/baptiste/.linuxbrew/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
  /home/baptiste/.linuxbrew/share/zsh/site-functions

fish completion has been installed to:
  /home/baptiste/.linuxbrew/share/fish/vendor_completions.d

==> Summary
  /.../Cellar/youtube-dl/2017.03.10: 11 files, 1.8M
```

Then:

```
$ brew info youtube-dl
...
==> Caveats
To use post-processing options, `brew install ffmpeg` or `brew install libav`.

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /home/baptiste/.linuxbrew/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
  /home/baptiste/.linuxbrew/share/zsh/site-functions

fish completion has been installed to:
  /home/baptiste/.linuxbrew/share/fish/vendor_completions.d
```

You can also retrieve formula-specific caveats (not completion stuff) with `brew info --json=v1`, e.g.:

```
$ brew info --json=v1 youtube-dl | jq .
[
  {
    "name": "youtube-dl",
    "full_name": "youtube-dl",
    "desc": "Download YouTube videos from the command-line",
    "homepage": "https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/",
    ...
    "caveats": "To use post-processing options, `brew install ffmpeg` or `brew install libav`.",
    ...
  }
]
```

Note I used [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) to prettify the output.